# NVG compatibility LED Lights

Tags: led, filter, light, input, keypad

For an avionics application I need to make a keypanel which has NVG compatible LED lights behind its keys. I am trying to understand how does the NVG compatibility (Night vision Goggles) relates to the LED light? If I put a high-glow green color LED behind a keyboard button will it be enough for making it NVG compatible? Or do I need to apply any specific filter on top of the LED and that filter will make a normal LED into a NVG compatible LED light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MIL-STD-3009](https://quicksearch.dla.mil/qsDocDetails.aspx?ident_number=209352) and MIL-L-85762 detail the spectrum requirements for NVIS compatible lighting, and include the sensitivity spectra for the for different classes of tubes.
[image]

The aim is to minimize the output of light that is in the sensitive area of the NVGs. For incandescent lighting this was an issue since most of the output is in infrared, but LEDs generally have fairly sharply defined outputs. You'll need to look at the datasheets of the LEDs you intend to use, but the overlap looks to be pretty small for this random green LED I had a datasheet for. It's a pity that the lighting has to be green, blue LEDs centered at 480nm output have no overlap at all.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to explore Green filter plastic film to attenuate the broad spectrum that although is only 1% , if your indicator is 1000 mcd the LEDs may still be brighter than your night target and affect the AGC from stray light.

https://images.app.goo.gl/S7bDxK96LuqbNx1x7

Normally we examine LEDs with a linear scale which does not show the low levels of spectra outside the centre.  But the above log scale only shows 2 decades, but imagine several decades.

Also we do not know how much attenuation is needed to make these indicators dark to the night vision photo-multiplier. Our eyes have a 100dB range amplified by the night vision, so be proactive.

I prefer true green 525nm LEDs.